# Django server starting then crashing

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Hi I just updated a couple of packages (including django) when I ran `python -Wa manage.py test` no problems where found but when i run the server an error occurs and I can't find where it is coming from.

I'm using django 3.0.4 and python 3.6

stack trace:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Jetbrains\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\193.6494.30\bin\runnerw64.exe" D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Projects/coursemanager/backend/manage.py runserver --noreload 8000
DEBUG 2020-03-07 13:50:28,401 selector_events 37100 Using selector: SelectSelector
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 07, 2020 - 13:50:31
Django version 3.0.4, using settings 'backend.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projects/coursemanager/backend/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 104, in run
    self.inner_run(None, **options)
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 64, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 45, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\backend\wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "D:\Projects\coursemanager\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 37, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Process finished with exit code 1
```

EDIT:

Added settings.py after request in the comments to include it.
settings.py:

```
import logging
import os
import sys

import logutils.colorize
import datetime

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'graphene_django',
    'course',
    'evaluation',
    'training',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_jwt',
    'import_export'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'https://localhost:3000',
    'https://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl-NL'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

DATE_FORMAT = "d-m-Y"

GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'shared.schema.schema',
    'MIDDLEWARE': [
        'graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware',
    ],
}

GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'shared.schema.custom_jwt_payload'
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static'),
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Comment: it's probably related to version of django, try django 2.2

Comment: It looks like you installed certain middleware that is likely not compatible with the version you use. Can you share relevant parts of the `settings.py` (including `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`)?

Comment: did u implement any middlewares, may be it needs more tweaking to be more compatible with dj 3.xx

Comment: I did not implement my own middleware. Edited the question and added settings

Answer (score 1):

I was my project in django 1.11 and with it in MIDDLEWARE it works.
Now i upgrade my project to django 3.2 and eliminate it from MIDDLEWARE. It works for me. Please see https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/quickstart.html In the documentation dont say you need add it to MIDDLEWARE.
Thanks @samir

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

For django 3.0 and django-graphql-jwt 0.3.0 you mustn't have `graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware` in the Django MIDDLWARE settings.

Only add the MIDDLEWARE section under GRAPHENE settings.

Removing `graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware` from the MIDDLWARE settings should fix the issue.

See the django-graphql-jwt installation doco here: https://pypi.org/project/django-graphql-jwt/0.3.0/